# How do I recover the BIOS password?

Tags: bios, password-recovery

I need help, but I really think I have blown it.

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and am having a ton of problems. So, I thought that I would try alighter version of Linux. However, I put in a BIOS password. I can't remember it and I can't find were I wrote it down.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Resetting your BIOS password varies from model to model.  It may just be a case removing the CMOS battery or there may be a link to short out.  Try googling "BIOS password reset" together with the make and model of your computer.  If that does not find a solution edit this question to include the make and model of your computer.

Answer (score 3):

Is your computer a laptop or a desktop? If it is a desktop: Close your computer, unplug it's power cable than open your computer's case, find your motherboards's bios battery and unplug it.

[image: Cmos battery]

Wait for 10-15 minutes and replug it. Your bios seetings will return to it's factory defaults and your bios password will be removed.

Answer (score 3):

There is another option you can try. This [site](http://dogber1.blogspot.com.br/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html) provides Python scripts to recover your password given a checksum which is displayed after entering an invalid password for the third time:

[image: Extracted from Dogbert's Blog]

*Image source: http://dogber1.blogspot.com.br/*

They're available for different vendors and hash encoding. Just pick the one that suits your computer.

I had this problem once. My friend forgot the password of his HP, so we used one script to recover it. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @0xC0000022L It means "provides". Sorry, haha! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

0xC0000022L mentioned that some machines now store the bios password in non-volatile memory so they stay even if the battery is removed.

There's a program called killcmos which might still do the job of resetting the password(and obviously other cmos settings) to default, as removing a battery would.

I have used killcmos successfully when I tried it many years ago.

Also a "warning", I have seen a computer lose access to a Printer, after CMOS was reset, because it had a BIOS setting for LPT1 set to disabled by default!

Answer (score 0):

BIOS password generally preserved by the system battery, so open your pc and remove the CMOS battery or cell and restart the pc.

Now it will not require the BIOS password, if you know the jumper shorting then try it for removing the old password and reset it.

watch the youtube videos:-
www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbXW6-PngZk

Comment: Actually the CMOS battery is mostly for the clock (RTC). Passwords can be stored in nonvolatile parts (e.g. flash).

Comment: @0xC0000022L When did they start doing that? And how common is it? Is it > 50%? Notice that the answer with 3 votes has suggested removing the battery too.

Comment: @barlop: I don't know when, but I have seen my share of machines where this is the case. May also depend on the brand, of course. In general I was more successful using the master passwords that can be used on the web. Also, didn't downvote it for this perceived flaw, btw ;)